# Get coordinates from web mercator projection to Lan & Lot (JavaScript/ node.js)

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, well-known-text, node-js

I have the WKT coordinates like below.

```
LINESTRING (16139582.976129573 -4541142.959679384,16139974.715899538 -4540837.211566243)
```

How can I get the Longitude and Latitude from that.

I am using GISCloud.

Comment: But that is Openlayers 3. I am using GISCloud

Comment: The solution there is "use the Proj4JS library" which is a JS library that works in any JS environment, and is in the npm.

Comment: @Spacedman : Seems like it is very good. Thank you